# C#I have made is a coI have made is a co

Tags: c#

The calculator I have made is a combination of textboxes and radiobuttons and when 'calculate' is clicked, I would like a message box to check the whole program and then (if necessary) display a message box saying something like 'the following areas still need completing' and then list those areas.

I know how to code a basic if lI have made is a co't know how to get it to check multiple textboxes and radiobuttons in one go.

The current code for the button is:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawForce = (Area2 * (StrengthCoeff / (WorkHardExp + 1)) * (Math.Pow(Math.Log(Area1 / Area2), WorkHardExp + 1)));
    DrawForce = Math.Round(DrawForce, 2);
    textBox7.Text = DrawForce.ToString() + " N";
}
```

I don't wish to copy the enter code onto here so I hope that will suffice

Thanks

Comment: `"a basic if loop"` - What's an "if loop"?  It's not really clear what you're asking or where you're stuck.  You can reference any controls on the form in this code, what isn't working?

Comment: wow.  `if loop` and `message box to check the whole program`.  You're dead to me, Bobby.

Comment: @SamAxe I'm new to this and I only used 'if' as an example to try and get people to understand what I'm talking about. If you have any suggestions please let me know

Comment: @BobWood: I think the point is that we don't know what you're talking about.  "if" isn't a loop structure, nor do we know how you're stuck or in what way the code isn't working.  We can't really suggest anything if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: There isn't a problem, the code works fine as it is. I'm just looking for ways to make it better. Is there any kind specific statement that could be used? Let me give an example.

Say I have 2 textboxes, a radio button and a button. When clicking the button, I would want it to check everything and tell me which buttons or radiobuttons were left blank.

That's what I'd like to do with my calculator, but with many more textboxes and radiobuttons. So, it's not that I need to change my code, I'm just looking for a way to start (I think)

Comment: Code reviews are off topic for SO.  try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to check many controls on the form in a loop.  There are a couple of ways to do this.

One way would be to create a class-level collection on the form which holds references to the controls.  For example, something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>
{
    TextBox1,
    TextBox2,
    TextBox3
};
```

Then you can examine it in a loop:

```
var errors = new List<string>();
foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox.Text))
        errors.Add(string.Format("{0} is empty.", textBox.Name));
// errors now contains the list of validation messages
```

The downside to this is that you'd need to manually keep the collection updated if you change the form.  If there aren't going to be many changes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Another option could be to loop through the `Controls` collection of the form.  Something like this:

```
var errors = new List<string>();
foreach (var control in Controls)
    if (control is TextBox)
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace((control as TextBox).Text))
            errors.Add(string.Format("{0} is empty.", (control as TextBox).Name));
// errors now contains the list of validation messages
```

This is more dynamic, but a little more brittle as well.  If there are any text boxes nested in other controls then this won't find those, you'd need to make this more recursive to loop through `control.Controls` as well.  That could get a little ugly, and might not be worth it if the form isn't likely to change.  But either way, it might look something like this:

```
private IList<string> GetErrorsForControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
            if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace((control as TextBox).Text))
                errors.Add(string.Format("{0} is empty.", (control as TextBox).Name));

        errors = errors.Concat(GetErrorsForControls(control.Controls));
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Then in your code you'd just invoke that method:

```
var errors = GetErrorsForControls(Controls);
```

---

To add validation for other types of controls besides text boxes, simply add other class-level collections or add other type checks in the loops.